# how to keep thread runing after request end in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a web application using .NET Framework 4.8, where I'm encountering issues with managing threads. Specifically, I'm creating background threads in my application, but they seem to get terminated unexpectedly, possibly due to garbage collection. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
public class AController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ResultModel Test()
    {
        TestService testService = new TestService();
        testService.DoSomething();
        return new ResultModel();
    }
}

public class TestService
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
            // Perform some work...
        });
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

When I make a request to this API, I receive a ResultModel, but shortly afterward, my program encounters an exception (Thread is Abort).

Can you help me understand why these background threads are being terminated and how I can ensure they continue running even after the response has been sent?

Comment: What are you really doing? What is the purpose? Some kind of asynchronous request? Some background task for housekeeping? Asp.Net does not work like a regular desktop application, you should not go creating threads however you want, you need to work within the execution model provided by Asp.Net.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using raw threads, consider using `Task.Run` to create a background task. This can be combined with `async/await`. When you use `Task.Run`, the task becomes part of the ASP.NET request pipeline, and it won't be abruptly terminated when the main request thread completes.

Here's the example by using `Task.Run`:

```
public class AController : ApiController
{
    private TestService testService = new TestService();

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ResultModel> Test()
    {
        await testService.DoSomethingAsync();
        return new ResultModel();
    }
}

public class TestService
{
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            // Perform some work...
        });
    }
}
```